# Going from Antlr 4.1 to 4.2

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a project that I am wanting to make in Java 8. Unfortunately, it looks like Antlr 4.1 does not support Java 8. Would it be an easy transition to replace the Antlr 4.1 library with a 4.2 library jar? Or would there be problems that I would encounter?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your current grammar uses ANTLR4 (and not ANTLR3 for example) you should be fine. Unless your application is dependent on some obscure bug in 4.1.

I have gone from 4.1 to 4.3 then 4.5 without having to make any ANTLR related changes to my application.

If I were you I would move from 4.1 straight to current version 4.6.